# Is there any simulator for ESP32-S2 or ESP32 chips?

Tags: esp32

I am working on an esp project and compiled my code by using the `esp32s2` toolchain and created a binary that ready to run on a real device. But I don't have a real device to test my binary. Is there any simulator to simulate the ESP32-S2 chip or the ESP32 chip?

Comment: price for modules and boards is in 2-6$ range. What is wrong with buying several boards and testing code properly at real hardware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try QEMU from https://github.com/espressif/qemu or https://github.com/Ebiroll/qemu_esp32

Not sure if they are supporting ESP32-S2, but it seems to be working with ESP32.

Answer (score 17):

You can use **[Wokwi](https://wokwi.com)** to simulate the **ESP32**, and soon also the **[ESP32-S2](https://github.com/wokwi/wokwi-features/issues/196)**.The Wokwi is a free online simulator for electronics, and it runs in your browser. This means you can simulate code that interacts with 3rd-party sensors, display modules, LEDs and many other common parts. There's also initial [support for WiFi simulation](https://github.com/wokwi/wokwi-features/issues/202), and the developers are working on extending it to support connecting to any host on the internet (e.g. HTTPS/MQTT)

### Simulator Examples

**Arduino Examples**

[Blink](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304633599712297536)

[Seven segment counter](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/305567166302782017)

[APA102 Color Cycles](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/308012505806930496) (TinyPico Board)

[WiFi Scanning](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/305569599398609473)

**MicroPython Examples**

[SSD1306 Example](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/305568836183130690)

[NeoPixels](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/305569065545499202)

[WiFi Scanning](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/305570169692881473)

**ESP-IDF Examples**

The following examples use the ESP-IDF functions. They are compiled using Arduino ESP32 Core:

[Blink using FreeRTOS API](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304209256260829762)

[Binary LED counter using FreeRTOS tasks](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304210422302507585)

[GPIO button input + interrupts](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304633599712297536)

https://docs.wokwi.com/guides/esp32

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Implementation of bouncing buttons looks missing :)

Comment: @cly https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/288681423014986248 here is the example for bouncing and debouncing

Trick is to enable the debounce parameter in the diagram.json file... 

 "bounce": "0"

Answer (score 0):

There's QEMU support for ESP32 and most recently added ESP32C3

Answer (score 0):

Hercules is one of the best simulator for ESP32 and related controllers

Comment: Yes Hercules is one of the best for ESp32 and like controllers.
And you can use the Putty also.